# How to bind Enum to combobox with empty field in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, enums

How to do I bind an enum value to a ComboBox and fill it with an empty field using Linq? I have tried:

```
public static List<object> GetDataSource(Type type, bool fillEmptyField = false)
{
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
         if (fillEmptyField)
         {
             var data =  Enum.GetValues(type)
                        .Cast<Enum>()
                        .Select(E => new { Key = (object)Convert.ToInt16(E), Value = ToolsHelper.GetEnumDescription(E) })
                        .ToList<object>();

             return data;
         }
         else
         {
            return Enum.GetValues(type)
              .Cast<Enum>()
              .Select(E => new { Key = Convert.ToInt16(E), Value = ToolsHelper.GetEnumDescription(E) })
              .ToList<object>();
          }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I don't know how to insert the empty field into the combobox, however Key is null and Value is an empty string. Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    public static List<object> GetDataSource(Type type, bool fillEmptyField = false)
    {
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            var data = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>()
                       .Select(E => new { Key = (object)Convert.ToInt16(E), Value = ToolsHelper.GetEnumDescription(E) })
                       .ToList<object>();

            var emptyObject = new {Key = default(object), Value = ""};

            if (fillEmptyField)
            {
                data.Insert(0, emptyObject); // insert the empty field into the combobox
            }
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: That seems like a workable approach to me, but the question asks for `Key` to be `null`, so it should be `Key = (object)null` or `Key = default(object)` rather than `Key = -1`.

Comment: @hvd, Nice catch. I will put default(object). Thanks