# bind enum to combobox plus one custom choice

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, enums

I've followed the advice given here : [How to bind Enum to combobox with empty field in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583072/2307070) but it gave me some unusable content:

[image: Result]

which is *not* what I would like to see... Here's the code I used to bind:

```
comboBox2.DataSource = GetDataSource(typeof (MessageLevel), true);
```

And here's the background:

```
public enum MessageLevel
{
    [Description("Information")]
    Information,
    [Description("Warning")]
    Warning,
    [Description("Error")]
    Error
}
----
public static string GetEnumDescription(string value)
{
    Type type = typeof(MessageLevel);
    var name = Enum.GetNames(type).Where(f => f.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(d => d).FirstOrDefault();

    if (name == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    var field = type.GetField(name);
    var customAttribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return customAttribute.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute)customAttribute[0]).Description : name;
}

public static List<object> GetDataSource(Type type, bool fillEmptyField = false)
{
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        var data = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>()
                   .Select(E => new { Key = (object)Convert.ToInt16(E), Value = GetEnumDescription(E.ToString()) })
                   .ToList<object>();

        var emptyObject = new { Key = default(object), Value = "" };

        if (fillEmptyField)
        {
            data.Insert(0, emptyObject); // insert the empty field into the combobox
        }
        return data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I make a correct binding and adding one empty entry?

Comment: Try to set `DisplayMemberPath="Value"` and `SelectedValuePath="Key"`

Comment: @Michael as it's winform (mea culpa, I didn't tag it at first) it's DisplayMember and ValueMember. If you want some rep... :)

Comment: What is the purpose of GetEnumDescription()?  It seems to try to access an attribute in the enum value.

Comment: @Ian yeah, I've pasted an old version of the enum, it's now fixed

Comment: @Thomas thanks, was thinking it's `WPF`.

Comment: @Thomas So why not add the 'blank' value to the enum?  It would make your code more readable and a smidge less complicated.  Off topic, I know, but just a comment...

Comment: @Ian because I don't want my fellow developers to be able to create a message with a level set to `Blank`... You see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to also set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties on ComboBox, so that it will know how to treat `Key` and `Value` properties.

```
comboBox2.DataSource = GetDataSource(typeof (MessageLevel), true);
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Key";
```